# hg can't merge branch

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch

I have a mercurial repository with a named branch branchA. The revision looks like this

```
default  --A-------------------------G
             \ 
branchA       \---B---C---D---E---F
```

The output of `hg branches` is:

```
default    193:817540244f12 
branchA    192:b7cac921fec3
```

What I want to do is to merge the change G in `default` to `branchA`. But when I try to update to branchA with `hg update branchA`, `hg branch` shows it's still in `default`. With `hg merge default`, mercurial complains "abort: nothing to merge (use 'hg update' or check 'hg heads')".
The `hg heads` output is:

```
changeset:   193:817540244f12
tag:         tip
parent:      188:7ccc08b69f25
...

changeset:   192:b7cac921fec3
branch:      branchA
```

Comment: What does it say when you do `hg update branchA`?

Comment: Does `branchA` show up when you run hg tags or hg bookmarks?